# Correct fread() application?

Tags: php, file, file-upload, fread, chunks

Say I'm uploading a chunked file and I have to recompose it. I know the total chunks and data from every iteration.

I founded code like this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_chunks; $i++) {

  $file = fopen($target_file.$i, 'rb');
  $buff = fread($file, 2097152);
  fclose($file);

  $final = fopen($target_file, 'ab');
  $write = fwrite($final, $buff);
  fclose($final);

  unlink($target_file.$i);
}
```

Apparently, the 2097152 value, has no meaning, at least to me. I read the php docs but couldn't understand too much. Could anyone explain me how I should choose that secon param of fread? And how the thing works?

Comment: It's how many bytes the function should read. Usually, we set the filesize in this parameter.

Comment: Ok. But how to apply this concept on chunked uploads? Should maybe be the size of the chunk itself then? or in other words total-filesize/number-of-chunks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is the amount of data to read, as your reading this in one chunk you have to be sure that it is enough to process any chunk.  The value you've set is 2MB, which may be enough, but you could change the code so that it reads it in smaller chunks and loops till the input is fully read.

I've also changed it to open the output file once and just write the contents as you go along...

```
$final = fopen($target_file, 'wb');   // Open for write and start from beginning of file
for ($i = 1; $i <= $num_chunks; $i++) {
  $file = fopen($target_file.$i, 'rb');
  while($buff = fread($file, 4096))  {
      fwrite($final, $buff);
  }
  fclose($file);

  unlink($target_file.$i);
}
fclose($final);
```